# How do I access compiled memory in WebAssembly from js

Tags: javascript, c++, webassembly

Consider the following C++ :

```
int MYVAR = 8;
```

It will compile from Clang/LLVM to the WASM bytecode inserted in the playground below.

WAST for readability :

```
(module
(table (;0;) 0 anyfunc)
(memory (;0;) 1)
(global (;0;) i32 (i32.const 0))
(export "MYVAR" (global 0))
(data (i32.const 0) "\08\00\00\00"))
```

MYVAR will expose a pointer to the variable when called from js.

*But how do I access the actual memory with the new js API?*

The memory constructor seems to *erase the entry* when initialising, but I´m not sure if I´m interpreting this correctly.

As a side note the Module does not have an exports property as specified in the [specs](http://webassembly.org/docs/js/), but this, again, might be a misinterpretation.

Playground:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>MEMORY ACCESS TEST</title>
</head> 
<div>
<h1 style="display: inline;">MEMORY LOCATION : </h1>
<h1 id='POINTER' style="display: inline;"></h1>
</div> 
<div>
<h1 style="display: inline;">VALUE : </h1>
<h1 id='VALUE' style="display: inline;"></h1>
</div>
<body>
<script>
 var bytecode = new Uint8Array([
 0x00, 0x61, 0x73, 0x6D, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x04, 0x84,
 0x80, 0x80, 0x80, 0x00, 0x01, 0x70, 0x00, 0x00, 0x05, 0x83,
 0x80, 0x80, 0x80, 0x00, 0x01, 0x00, 0x01, 0x06, 0x86, 0x80,
 0x80, 0x80, 0x00, 0x01, 0x7F, 0x00, 0x41, 0x00, 0x0B, 0x07,
 0x89, 0x80, 0x80, 0x80, 0x00, 0x01, 0x05, 0x4D, 0x59, 0x56,
 0x41, 0x52, 0x03, 0x00, 0x0B, 0x8A, 0x80, 0x80, 0x80, 0x00,
 0x01, 0x00, 0x41, 0x00, 0x0B, 0x04, 0x08, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
 0x00, 0x96, 0x80, 0x80, 0x80, 0x00, 0x07, 0x6C, 0x69, 0x6E,
 0x6B, 0x69, 0x6E, 0x67, 0x03, 0x81, 0x80, 0x80, 0x80, 0x00,
 0x04, 0x04, 0x81, 0x80, 0x80, 0x80, 0x00, 0x04
 ]);
 WebAssembly.instantiate(bytecode).then(function(wasm) {
 console.log(wasm.module);
 console.log(wasm.instance);
 let pointer = wasm.instance.exports.MYVAR;
 document.getElementById('POINTER').innerHTML = pointer; 
 let memory = new WebAssembly.Memory({initial : 1});
 let intView = new Uint32Array(memory.buffer);
 document.getElementById('VALUE').innerHTML = intView[pointer];
 });
 </script>
 </body>

 </html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`MYVAR` is a global. That's a totally separate addressable unit from the Memory section. It contains individual scalar values.

You seem to be trying to access the Memory section instead. You can indeed use an `i32` global as a pointer, as you could any other `i32`, but it can't access the Memory automagically. You have to export your memory too!

Try:

```
(module
(table (;0;) 0 anyfunc)
(memory (;0;) 1)
(global (;0;) i32 (i32.const 0))
(export "MYVAR" (global 0))
(export "MYMEM" (memory 0)) ;; New!
(data (i32.const 0) "\08\00\00\00"))
```

And:

```
WebAssembly.instantiate(bytecode).then(function(wasm) {
 console.log(wasm.module);
 console.log(wasm.instance);
 let pointer = wasm.instance.exports.MYVAR;
 document.getElementById('POINTER').innerHTML = pointer; 
 let memory = wasm.instance.exports.MYMEM; // New!!
 let intView = new Uint32Array(memory.buffer);
 document.getElementById('VALUE').innerHTML = intView[pointer];
 });
```

Comment: Works. Thanks. I´m concluding the LLVM backend for wasm is still WIP ;) Another observation: If you wasm2wast the bytes from the question and then wast2wasm the result you get a different and smaller bytecode. wabt is supposed to be one to one. yes?

Comment: Yes, the WebAssembly LLVM backend is still WIP but should be mostly functional. Exporting memory seems like something that should work. You should file a bug.